# How to create a controller from a button id in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to create a controller from a button id in CakePHP.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 <button id="initial_pay" class="btn btn-action" onclick="payWithPaystack()">Initial payment - N5,000</button>

 public function initial_pay() {
    $amount= 55;
        $credit = $this->calculateCredit($amount, true);
        $uid = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->CreditBalances->addCredit($uid, floatval($credit));
}
```

How can I achieve this so that when users click on the button, the action code will be executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
'Initial payment - N5,000',
    array(
        'id' => 'initial_pay',
        'class' => 'btn btn-action',
        'controller' => 'myController',
        'action' => 'initial_pay',
        'full_base' => true
    )
);
```

More info: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

But if you want the user to click the button and stay in the same page without reloading, you'll need to call mycontroller/initial_pay with ajax.